# Change IE developer tools user agent settings programatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, internet-explorer

I'm running some automated tests and would like to know if there is a way to control the user agent string setting shown below? Either by modifying the registry or using some API (similar to the [InternetZoneManager](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Interfaces.IInternetZoneManager)).

I know about the `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\User Agent` registry key, but as far as I can tell, this IE setting overrides that entry.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can just change the local compatibility view file to make ie render with those configurations you want.

Comment: @VitorCanova Thanks for the tip. Where do I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I think you will have better luck if you change the Compatibility View Settings file.

The file is located in this path:

> File:\\%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Internet
>   Explorer\IECompatData\iecompatdata.xml

In this file you can configure the way IE will render and witch User Agent will be provided for every site.

**Edit**

You need to focus in these elements:

- ua: It has the User Agent information. It has an id you can use as following.
- domain: Here you set witch `uaString` and if it overrides the X-UA-Compatible tag on the page.

Example:

```
<ua id="Dummy">
    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Dummy2
</ua>

<domain docMode="EmulateIE10" 
        versionVector="10" 
        uaString="Dummy" 
        featureSwitch="overrideXUACompatible:true">
            YourSiteHere.com
</domain>
```

In this example I have a `ua` called `IE10 Trident 6.0 Token` and I'm using it to target the `test.com` site. I even had set the `overrideXUACompatible` in such a way the browser will ignore it on the page.

**Edit 2**

To make IE read the `iecompatdata.xml` file you need to follow this steps:

- Close ALL IE instances (check TaskManager)
- Open a blank tab on IE and click CTRL + SHIFT + DEL.
- Uncheck the first option and mark all the other and click Delete.
- Wait for the yellow bar in the bottom show the data was cleared.
- Make sure "*Use Microsoft Compatibility list*" is checked in Compatibility View Settings.
- Open your page. It will load your changed Compatibility View file.

[image]

You can find more information about Compatibility View Settings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg622935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, do you know which xml item that is used to select the UA string?

Comment: I adited my answer. Take a look.

Comment: Thanks but I tried that, not sure what I missed but if I add the string `<domain docMode="EmulateIE10" versionVector="10" uaString="Chrome 19" featureSwitch="overrideXUACompatible:true">http://www.xhaus.com/headers</domain>` and visit `http://www.xhaus.com/headers` I still don't get a new header. Chrome 19 is defined in the XML: `<ua id="Chrome 19">Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5</ua>`

Comment: I don't think you can use a folder there like you diid in `/headers` part. Could you try again? Maybe you should close all IE instances, even in the TaskManager.

Comment: Wow. No. Didn't work. Very strange. I Just remember when I wanted run flash on Surface i needed to change this file. I remember I needed to clean cache too. Will try again.